# Sleep at random intervals in a minute

Tags: php, sleep

Currently I have the following :

```
$counter = 0;
$actions_per_minute = 6;
$sleep_time = (int)(60 / $actions_per_minute);
do{

    sleep($sleep_time);
    $counter++;

} while($counter < $actions_per_minute);
```

With this code the script would sleep every **10 seconds** is it possible to have it set at random intervals over the **60 seconds** just not every **10 seconds** so maybe **twice** in the first **10 seconds**, sleep for 7 seconds etc....

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a list of N random numbers ($actions_per) that add up to a certain value ($total_time):

```
$sleep_times = [];
$actions_per = 6;
$total_time = 60;

$sum = 0;
for ($action = 0; $action < $actions_per; $action++ ) {
    $random_interval = rand(0,$total_time);
    array_push($sleep_times, $random_interval);
    $sum = $sum + $random_interval;
}

$scaleFactor = $sum / $total_time;

$checksum = 0;
foreach( $sleep_times as $sleep_time ){
    $scaled = $sleep_time / $scaleFactor;
    $checksum = $checksum + $scaled;
    echo $scaled."\n";
}
echo "Check:".$checksum;
```

Result:

$actions_per = 6, $total_time = 60:

```
9.2523364485981
3.9252336448598
12.056074766355
16.822429906542
11.495327102804
6.4485981308411
Check:60
```

$actions_per = 12, $total_time = 60:

```
9.0532544378698
8.5207100591716
6.5680473372781
2.3076923076923
9.0532544378698
3.3727810650888
3.5502958579882
4.6153846153846
4.4378698224852
2.1301775147929
4.792899408284
1.5976331360947
Check:60
```

$actions_per = 6, $total_time = 120:

```
23.907156673114
18.568665377176
3.0174081237911
25.299806576402
23.675048355899
25.531914893617
Check:120
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build an array of sleep times that add up to 60 seconds, and then pop them off the array as you use them:

```
$times = [];
while (array_sum($times) < 60) {
    $min = 1;
    $max = 60 - array_sum($times);
    $times[] = mt_rand($min, $max);
}
```

Might wrap that in a function, so you can get a new array of them every minute. Then when you use it:

```
sleep(array_pop($times));
```

Comment: Nice response, although the only problem with this doesn't stick with the `$actions_per_minute` functionality I'm intending to use.